# Unable to pull google/appengine-go docker image

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy my appengine go application to managed vm, and I keep getting this error

```
Pulling image: google/appengine-go
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/honeybooboo/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 170, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/honeybooboo/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 166, in main
    _cli.Execute()
  File "/home/honeybooboo/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 385, in Execute
    post_run_hooks=self.__post_run_hooks, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/home/honeybooboo/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/frontend.py", line 274, in _Execute
    pre_run_hooks=pre_run_hooks, post_run_hooks=post_run_hooks)
  File "/home/honeybooboo/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 928, in Run
    result = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/home/honeybooboo/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/app_commands/setup_managed_vms.py", line 39, in Run
    args.image_version)
  File "/home/honeybooboo/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/pull.py", line 54, in PullBaseDockerImages
    util.PullSpecifiedImages(docker_client, image_names, version, bucket)
  File "/home/honeybooboo/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/util.py", line 232, in PullSpecifiedImages
    'Error pulling {image}: {e}'.format(image=image_name, e=e))
googlecloudsdk.appengine.lib.images.util.DockerPullError: Error pulling google/appengine-go: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("No such id: localhost:49156/google/appengine-go")
```

My docker version

```
Client version: 1.3.0
Client API version: 1.15
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): c78088f
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.3.0
Server API version: 1.15
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): c78088f
```

My Gcloud version

> Google Cloud SDK 0.9.37

```
app 2014.11.18
app-engine-go-linux-x86_64 1.9.15
app-engine-java 1.9.15a
app-engine-managed-vms 2014.11.03
app-engine-python 1.9.15a
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.6
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
compute 2014.11.25
core 2014.11.25
core-nix 2014.10.20
dns 2014.11.06
gae-go 2014.11.25
gae-go-nix 2014.09.10
gae-python 2014.05.06
gcutil 1.16.5
gcutil-nix 1.16.5
gsutil 4.6
gsutil-nix 4.6
preview 2014.11.18
preview-extensions-linux-x86_64 4.1
sql 2014.11.18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry that you're having problems. We're aware of this issue and it is already fixed in the next SDK release (coming out in a week). As a temporary workaround please try to run

```
gcloud --verbosity debug preview app setup-managed-vms
```

(and choose Go in the list of options)
several times (until success) to get the base image for go runtime.

Another options is to try pulling the base go image (google/appengine-go) from containers-prod

bucket using `google/docker-registry` https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/google/docker-registry/

Pull the google/docker-registry

```
docker pull google/docker-registry
```

Get your credentials

```
gcloud auth print-refresh-token
```

Store your refresh token and your bucket (containers prod in a registry-params.env file)

```
cat registry-params.env
GCP_OAUTH2_REFRESH_TOKEN=your-refresh-token
GCS_BUCKET=containers-prod
```

Run registry

```
docker run -d --env-file=registry-params.env -p 5000:5000 google/docker-registry
```

Pull the image

```
docker pull localhost:5000/google/appengine-go
```

Retag the image

```
docker tag localhost:5000/google/appengine-go google/appengine-go
```

Remove old tag containing registry name

```
 docker rmi localhost:5000/google/appengine-go
```

Check your image is in there. You'll see something like

```
docker images | grep google
```

You'll see something like

```
google/appengine-go                  latest              35ef8e2a9c5e        13 days ago         206 MB
```

Don't forget to stop your registry container

```
docker ps
docker stop <CONTAINER ID>
```

Comment: Is it the same for the google/appengine-java docker image? I get an error at the `docker pull localhost:5000/google/appengine-java` step (substituted `go` with `java`) which is `Error pulling image (latest) from localhost:5000/google/appengine-java, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (3acec9a6a6593a35064dba416e0d0b4a08b25a51760ace859095f7ac8e89e6c5)`

Comment: Also, Is it necessary to enable billing before to do this? I want to test locally.

Comment: please let us know here when the next version will be available

Comment: @domenicop I am also stuck with the same error `Error pulling image (latest) from localhost:5000/google/appengine-python27, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (f01dc3167ff18445bad4a9060cfbb51b3cbec2cf36ba705492d5dd4f1c8e2349)`. Although I am running it for appengine-python27, it should still work.

Comment: In the docker server logs I see this `time="2014-12-13T16:17:28Z" level="debug" msg="Error contacting registry: Get http://localhost:5000/v1/images/f01dc3167ff18445bad4a9060cfbb51b3cbec2cf36ba705492d5dd4f1c8e2349/layer: read tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: i/o timeout"`

Comment: Same issue, have tried with boot2docker (several versions) with several versions of docker client on OS 10.10. Have a also tried within an Ubuntu Server x64 VM with the same result.

`ERROR: Error pulling image (latest) from localhost:49153/google/appengine-java, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (9d9e1bf3da09a6bce1fc48db00179346ee09cacc0bb65a01d0486fe86249f9e0)`

Comment: There is some very helpful information in this answer, but @goranek did it solve your problem? Or anybody? I'm worried that because this answer is accepted the issue appears to be resolved, but my searches have not turned up anyone who solved this.

Comment: I'm currently seeing the same inability to grab images... fails with something like `ERROR: Error: image google/appengine-go:latest not found
INFO: Exception Unable to pull the image to/from the registry: "Error: image google/appengine-go:latest not found" thrown in ProgressHandler. Retrying.`